# Switch day and month in date php

Tags: php, date

I have string holding a date like

```
$date_1 =   '24/12/2010 23:59:59';
```

I want to convert it to

```
  $dte_2 = '12/24/2010 23:59:59';
```

What would be the fastest way to do this in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pattern is always going to be 24/12/2010, you could explode the array on '/', switch the values of [0] and [1] and then implode the array again:

```
$date_1 = '24/12/2010 23:59:59';
$array = explode('/', $date_1);
$tmp = $array[0];
$array[0] = $array[1];
$array[1] = $tmp;
unset($tmp);
$date_2 = implode('/', $array);
```

Probably not the most elegant of solutions, but works if the 24/12/2010 pattern is consistent.

Comment: why use the hard way when there exist extra funtions?

Comment: Good solution even it is hard, is there a fastest way to do it?

Comment: @cMinor if you're going to format more than one string you could put it into a function, something like:

`function swapDate($string) {
  $array = explode('/', $string);
  $tmp = $array[0];
  $array[1] = $array[0];
  $array[0] = $tmp;
  return implode('/', $array);
}`

Answer (score 6):

You can do :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '24/12/2010 23:59:59');

echo $date->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: If it happens that I do not have  PHP > 5.3 in the server...?

Comment: then you're allowed to use the hard way... with explode etc. (btw. it's >= php 5.3)

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_parse_from_format` and then `strftime` on the result with the appropriate modifiers.

```
date('m/d/Y H:i:s',date_parse_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', $date_1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do below code:

```
date('m/d/Y h:i:s", strtotime($date_1));
```

Comment: this fails. only $dte_2 is a valid date for strtotime